# How do I select a numerical field in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have data that looks like: `{"id": "abc", "1":"2", "3":"5"}`

I'm trying to select this data with this SQL query:

```
SELECT c.3 FROM c WHERE c.id = '102'
```

This gives me a syntax error. I also tried `c.'3'` and `"c.3"` the and `c."3"`, but none of those worked.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like:

```
SELECT c["1"], c["3"] FROM c WHERE c.id = '102'
```

It will produce an output like:

```
[
    {
        "1": "2",
        "3": "5"
    }
]
```